# When receiving a push message on Android12 (API Level 31, 32) "Could not send notification" log is output

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, android-12

I would like some advice.
I'm implementing push messages with Firebase messaging.
On Android 11 or earlier (API Level 30 or lower), it is notified without any problem,
Not notified on Android12 (API Level 31, 32).

Looking at the console log, the following log was output.

I've looked at other articles and tried and errored, but I haven't been able to solve it.
If you have any knowledge, could you give me some advice?

When I checked the detailed log,
It was crashing with the following error.
An exception occurred in the source code of the android-28 SDK.
What are some ways to solve this?
I wish I could specify FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE ...
As much as possible, I am thinking that it can be supported without upgrading the version of react-native-firebase.

[Console Log]
(app name) E/DisplayNotificationTask: Failed to send notification
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: (app name): Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
at io.invertase.firebase.notifications.DisplayNotificationTask.createIntent(DisplayNotificationTask.java:474)
at io.invertase.firebase.notifications.DisplayNotificationTask.doInBackground(DisplayNotificationTask.java:377)
at io.invertase.firebase.notifications.DisplayNotificationTask.doInBackground(DisplayNotificationTask.java:32)
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

～～～

[Info] 07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: Error: Could not send notification
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: createErrorFromErrorData@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1730:26
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1689:51
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: __invokeCallback@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2286:23
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2012:34
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: __guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2200:15
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2011:21
07-14 09:07:00.379  7341  7406 W ReactNativeJS: invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]

[Environment]

"react-native": "~0.60.6"

"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0"

[Source]

```
async componentDidMount() {
    // do stuff while splash screen is shown
    // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen

    SplashScreen.hide();

    // AppState
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);

    // active
    Api._appState = 'active';

    :
    :

    Api.initializeNVSlideMenuController();

    this.onTokenRefreshListener = Firebase
    .messaging()
    .onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
        console.log('Refreshed FCM token: ', fcmToken);
    })

    const notificationOpen = await Firebase
    .notifications()
    .getInitialNotification()
    if (notificationOpen) {
        //console.log("xxxx")
    }

    const channel = new Firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
        'channel_1',
        'yyyy',
        Firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
    );
    await Firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    this.notificationOpenedListener = Firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        var badgeCount = 0;
        if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
            badgeCount = notification.ios.badge;
        }else{
            badgeCount = notification.data.android_badge;
        }

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            Firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
        }

        :
        :
    })

    this.notificationListener = Firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotification(notification => {
        var badgeCount = 0;
        if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
            badgeCount = notification.ios.badge;
            const localNotif = new Firebase.notifications.Notification()
                                .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
                                .setTitle(notification.title)
                                .setBody(notification.body)
                                .setSound(notification.data.sound)
                                .ios.setBadge(badgeCount);
                              
            Firebase.notifications().displayNotification(localNotif);

        }else{
            badgeCount = notification.data.android_badge;
            const androidNotification = notification
                .android.setChannelId(notification.android.channelId)
                .android.setPriority(Firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
                .setSound(notification.data.sound);

            Firebase.notifications().displayNotification(androidNotification);
        }

        :
        :
    })
}
```

[Console Log (after add catch())]

[Info] 07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS: 'e', { [Error: Could not send notification]
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   framesToPop: 1,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   nativeStackAndroid:
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:    [ { methodName: 'checkFlags',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 375,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'PendingIntent.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'getActivityAsUser',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 458,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'PendingIntent.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'getActivity',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 444,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'PendingIntent.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'getActivity',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 408,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'PendingIntent.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'createIntent',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 474,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'DisplayNotificationTask.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'doInBackground',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 377,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'DisplayNotificationTask.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'doInBackground',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        lineNumber: 32,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:        file: 'DisplayNotificationTask.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'call', lineNumber: 394, file: 'AsyncTask.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'run', lineNumber: 266, file: 'FutureTask.java' },
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:      { methodName: 'run', lineNumber: 305, file: 'AsyncTask.java' } ],
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   userInfo: null,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   code: 'notification/display_notification_error',
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   line: 1730,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   column: 26,
07-14 21:35:57.943 21128 21211 I ReactNativeJS:   sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }

Answer (score 1):

Because using: `react-native-firebase v5.5.6`

To fix this issue:
Make sure: AndroidManifest.xml android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml :

```
android:exported="false"
```

in all service contain name like "firebase"
[image]

- Go to DisplayNotificationTask.java in :

> node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/notifications/DisplayNotificationTask.java

Find `PendingIntent.getActivity` and `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`
And replace

```
return PendingIntent.getActivity(
  context,
  notificationId.hashCode(),
  intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

with

```
int flags = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId.hashCode(), intent, flags);
```

and then replace

```
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
  context,
  notificationId.hashCode(),
  intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

with

```
int flags = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId.hashCode(), intent, flags);
```

[image]

save the code => sync project => run again to fix this

**update 29/11/2022:**
in build.gradle/app :

```
dependencies {

    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0" 
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:20.2.0" 
}
```

and

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
...

    defaultConfig {
...
        targetSdkVersion 31
}
```

sync and run app again